# Passing an Array to Function with "..."

Tags: python, arrays, function, ironpython

I am using an api that has the following function declaration:

API Expects:

```
ReprioritizeBoundaries(["NAME:NewOrder", <BoundName>, <BoundName>,...])
```

I have an array that I have created with all the BoundNames. Is there any way I can pass the array into the function such that it treats it like an argument list?

What I want to do:

```
array=[BoundName1, BoundName2, BoundName3]
ReprioritizeBoundaries(["NAME:NewOrder", array])
```

Update: 
I am using Python (IronPython (if it makes a difference))

Comment: Your `array` variable is not, technically, an array.  It's a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just concatenate the two lists:

```
array=[BoundName1, BoundName2, BoundName3]
ReprioritizeBoundaries(["NAME:NewOrder"] + array)
```